# First Time installation issue

Tags: boot, usb

I am not sure if this is something I am doing wrong, or if the computer I am using just can't do it this way, but I can't seem to load Xubuntu 14.04 on an old desktop. It is an old computer that was given to me as the previous owner got a replacement. I reformatted the hard drive, as that was the main reason it was given to me. Since then, it's basically been sitting in my pile of parts not knowing what to do with until I decided to try out installing Ubuntu on it. I have a 16GB USB stick that I downloaded the installer on to (formatted to NTFS) but it won't load past the Dell splash screen. I have set up the boot order to look for removable device first, then San Disk Cruzer second, and also selected to boot directly from the stick in the boot options, but it will just sit on a black screen after loading through post. I let it sit overnight but still no change. So, I have two questions:

1. Where did I go wrong?
2. Can I use my slave cables to hook up the hard drive directly to my main PC and download the same installer on there, then choose to boot from HD first?

   Or would that need a different installer?

Comment: How did you create installer. The install software to flash drive normally makes it FAT32. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb What are system specs. CPU, RAM & Video card/chip?

Comment: Originally it was in FAT32 format but that had the same issue.  So I tried to  find an answer to why it wouldn't load and found one forum saying that formatting the stick as NTSF helped them, so I tried that, but it still had the same issue.  The system specs, I am not 100% sure on as I am not at home, but I believe they are:

CPU-- Intel Pentium Processor N3700


RAM--  4GB Single Channel DDR3

Graphics-- Just Intel HD Integrated Graphics

Comment: But you did use a tool like Unetbootin to create the bootable stick right? You cannot just download the iso and copy it onto the stick... Use Unetbootin or dd or something...

Comment: I did not.  Like I said, I'm an idiot and this is my first time installing it this way.  I'll try it this way when I get home.  I'm going to guess that is why it won't load anything.  Is there a better source for it then the one from Source Forge?

Answer (score 0):

When you do the install - do it in terminal mode - that way you can see what the installer is stuck on. Many years ago - I have similar problems with a strange Network card - which the install process rather freaked out on.

Which version of the Ubuntu 14.04 are you trying to install AMD or Intel ? And what chip set is your old machine ...